# Would it be possible to grow bamboo on the Earth's moon?

Tags: science-based, biology, flora

Having somewhat successfully raised bamboo plants myself, I know that they're hardy plants. However, our moon is a pretty different story. If we were to bring bamboo to the moon and maintain a small shelter consisting of the basic water, air, and protection from pure sunlight, would it be able to grow? As a sorta follow-up to this, how tall would it be able to get and how long would the plant be able to live?

Comment: what happens to them is they are 2 weeks without light? Moons days/nights are 2 weeks long.

Comment: Artificial light would be provided at all times. The plants would be sheltered from the sun rays, producing the need for a different light source to begin with.

Comment: no problems then, if you supply with good soil and minerals etc - will grow as usual.

Comment: bamboo without protection would burn and become ash during day and freeze then shatter in crystals  during night one the moon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You supply everything to its liking, so why not? Just *gravity*! You could use a centrifuge if necessary. So, you can provide an artificial environment to its liking no matter how picky it is.

It will grow the same height as it does anywhere.

Comment: plants are ok with gravity, as nasa says. They are light driven, in therms where and what should grow. Only problem in 0 gravity is water distribution in soil.